# combine order of complex and simple properties in display/editor ForModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I combine order of properties from complex and simple properties? e.g.

```
public class Car
{
    public string Color {get;set;}
    public string Engine {get;set;}
}


public class Report
{
    public Car Car {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and order which i want in view using Display/EditorForModel is:

Color
Name
Engine

is it possible?

thanks

Comment: What's the language? Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous types in C#, look at this example:-

```
Car car = new Car { Color = "Red", Engine = "E1" };
            Report report =  new Report { Cars = car , Name = "Car1" };
            var Result = new { Color = report.Cars.Color, Name = report.Name, Engine = report.Cars.Engine };
```